# How does acting as an RDP host affect UDP visibility/routing?

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

This is an odd one.

My work desktop runs a chat app that is udp based. It is for chat within the office.

When I used gotomypc, I could use the chat app fine.

But when I use remote desktop to connect to my work desktop, the chat app loses visibility to the local subnet. (I can repro the problem just using rdp from a machine on the local subnet, but first noticed it when I vpn in from off site.)

It is almost like the routing table of the work PC is changed when I rdp to it. But that makes no sense, and ONLY this one chat app is affected.

The chat app runs on udp 8168

Another way of asking the question is: What happens to UDP networking/routing on a host machine when a remote system does remote desktop to the host?

Is it possible that there is a virtual network interface that only exists when the machine is an rdp host (and that the chat app loses connection to the main network interface), or ?

How to chase?

Note:
Fiddler does not see udp traffic, and is not helpful.
nslookup is not relevant, as the chat app uses all ip addresses and not domain names (it is for local chat on local subnet only)

Comment: What port is the chat app running on? If it is 3389 (RDP), then maybe that is the cause. Otherwise, it might be that the respective redirections of Remote Desktop (e.g.: drive redirection, clipboard redirection etc.) are not working well. I suggest installing Fiddler and tracking the calls that the chat app makes.

Comment: @cdavid OP enhnahced...

Comment: I would still install Fiddler on the remote machine: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler - and then point it to the chat app (possibly enable SSL decryption if the chat app uses SSL) and look at all the incoming/outgoing requests to the chat client.

Comment: That + nslookup + ping would be your best bet on where to go forward :)